# Detect Home button long press event in background

Tags: ios, iphone, background, long-press, home-button

How can I detect Home button long press like 4 second or more event in my app which is already running in background? Is it possible to so because app is already running in background and if user long press home button of the device for 4 second or more can i detect the event in my background running app and if possible than will Apple approve this for app store?

Comment: You won't have the control on Home button?

Answer (score 1):

No that is not possible. As you should know, a long press on the home button brings up Siri. Your app would interfere with that. Also, I don't believe Apple allows access to the home button event like that.

Lastly; while your app is in the background, it goes into a suspend state after a short while and no events run. The only thing the app can do is receive push notifications - unless you have been given special access to audio / gps functions from Apple themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : Not possible. not at least with public method and want your app to be on Appstore.

For the Research purpose, you might want to try use private method and do your R&D with it. it might be possible.